# Is there a way in QGIS to change polygons in one layer to the outer boundary in another layer?

Tags: shapefile, qgis

I have two shapefiles. The first is the Shapefile of the United States (orange layer) with each state as a polygon. The second shapefile is the 2022 Congressional Districts based on 2020 Census Blocks which have many odd polygon shapes (purple layer). Is there a way to keep the polygons in the Congressional District layer but have the external boundaries match the USA Layer? I am not sure if this can be done or not or if I am missing something.

[image: 2022 Congressional Districts Layer]

[image: USA Layer Overlayed on Congressional Districts]

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and trial and error, I found the answer. You can complete this action by going to

Processing Toolbox > Vector Overlay > Clip >
Input Layer: Congressional Districts (with the oversized polygons)
Overlay Layer: USA (the polygons that show the size of the polygons I want)
Click Run

[Screenshot of the QGIS Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFcf4.png)